# unable to display json data on fullcalender control

Tags: php, jquery

```
{
    "date":"2017-02-13",
    "start":"2017-02-13 12:13:53",
    "end":"2017-02-13 12:14:05",
    "attendance":"P"
}
```

this is json data which I got from mysql on success function but the data was not rendered on calender. can any one tell me?

here is my event :

```
    events: [],

    events: function (start, end, timezone, callback)
     {

        var data = {                

                    action : "attendance_records",
                    userid : userid
              };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "model_attendance_table.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            { 

                var events = [];

                $(data).each(function(){

                    events.push({

                        title: 'title',     
                        start:$(this).attr('start'),
                        end:$(this).attr('end')

                    });


                });
                callback(events);

            }

        }); 
     }
```

and also I got error that callback is not defined.

Comment: What calendar solution are you using? I think you need to read its documentation and see what date format does it support.

Comment: fullCalendar control.

Comment: [This one](https://fullcalendar.io/)?

Comment: I just want to display the timing which is in start and end on that day so what should I do for that?

Comment: Yeah, that one only.

Comment: From the [example](https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/demos/basic-views.html) source code, it seems to support [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. I think you should reformat "2017-02-13 12:13:53" to something like "2017-02-13T12:13:53" and try again.

Comment: Also, instead of doing `$(data).each`, you should simply loop it through as a javascript array. `$(data).each` is for DOM elements.

Comment: Still Not working...even after changing date format and iterating using javascript.

Comment: Can you share the result of a `console.log(data)` inside of the `success` callback?

Comment: `callback` is defined in your demonstrated code. There is some error caused by the code you didn't show. Please share more of your code in order to get help for the `callback is not defined` issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this. It works for me.

```
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url that return json',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                userid: localStorage.getItem("userid"),
                start: start.unix(),
                end: end.unix()
            },
            success: function (doc) {
                alert(doc);
                alert(JSON.stringify(doc));
                var events = [];
                $(doc).each(function () {

                    events.push({
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),
                        start: $(this).attr('start'),
                        end: $(this).attr('end')
                    });
                });
                callback(events);

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
                alert("fail");
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!' + err);
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                // alert("Local completion callback." + status);
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple issues with your code:

### 1. Incorrect use of JSON data

Since your data of your [$.ajax]http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call is of `dataType: 'json'`, the resulting data is not a DOM object (like in the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) where `dataType: 'xml'`). So instead of:

```
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 

    var events = [];

    $(data).each(function(){
        events.push({
            title: 'title',     
            start:$(this).attr('start'),
            end:$(this).attr('end')
        });
    });
    callback(events);
}
```

You should do this:

```
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 

    var events = [];

    // ** notice the difference here **
    $.each(data, function(eventData){
        events.push({
            title: 'title',     
            start: eventData.start,
            end:   eventData.end
        });
    });
    callback(events);
}
```

### 2. `callback is undefined`

Frankly, if the code is like what you provided, this error should not have been here. So you need to demonstrate more code to get a concrete answer. My guess is you could have mistakes in your close brackets positions.

The `callback` function is an argument of your `events` value. So any `callback` reference should be within that same function closure. That means if you define your `success` callback function outside of the `events` function scope, this error can happen.

If you're unfamiliar, please read more about [scoping in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will try what you have said. but my earlier code is working fine and callback error is gone now.